# iOS MKAnnotationView repeated drops instead of reusing pins

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have set up an `MKMapView` with `MKAnnotationView`s for a bunch of locations. I have asynchronous requests set up to a server that returns locations within the given area on the screen at any given time, making another request when the user drags the map.

However, pins drop in places where pins already exist instead of reusing the ones that are already there. I thought the lines in my `viewForAnnotation` method:

```
MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"Pin"];


if(pinView == nil)
{
    pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"Pin"] autorelease];
    [pinView setAnimatesDrop:YES];
}
else
{
    [pinView setAnnotation:annotation];
}
```

would take care of it, but it doesn't. Maybe I'm misunderstanding the purpose of those lines of code.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Obviously I don't want superfluous annotations on the map, and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to look through the annotations already on the map and decide whether the pins from the server are already placed or not. If you have an unique id you can use that, or else compare the latitude and longitude of each pin.

The purpose of the code you wrote is this: Views are expensive to create, so when a pin is not visible, its view can be recycled and reused for another annotation.

Comment: Awesome, I ended up just comparing some qualities of the custom annotations. Thanks!